# Handle message in MFC

Tags: multithreading, timer, mfc

I have created a simple program about CDialog and Timer in MFC.

The problem I have encountered, I think it is very normal but i cannot explain how MFC handle message in one or many threads.

The mainly source code of program:

```
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
     CDialog::OnInitDialog();
     ...
     SetTimer(1, 10000, NULL);

     return TRUE;
}
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_START, OnBtnStartClicked)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDlg::OnBtnStartClicked()
{
    DisplayMessage(1);
}

void CMyDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDTimer)
{
     if (nIDTimer == 1)
     {
         KillTimer(1);
         DisplayMessage(2);
         SetTimer(1, 10000, NULL);
     }
}

void CMyDlg::DisplayMessage(INT nID)
{
    if (nID == 1)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Button Clicked"));
    }
    else if (nID == 2)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Timer timeout"));
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

I debug program with following steps:

1. Set break points in two functions: OnBtnStartClicked() and OnTimer() and run in debug  mode.
2. Click on Start button, the pointer of Visual Studio stops in OnBtnStartClicked(). Open Threads window, I see that the code is executed in "Main Thread".
3. Press F5 to continue. A message box is displayed. And I do nothing next.
4. In the next few seconds, the pointer of VS stops in OnTimer(). I also see in the Thread window and see that the code is also executed in "Main Thread".
5. Press F5 to continue. The second message box is display.

That makes me confused is: in Step 3, because I do nothing next, the "Main Thread" is temporary paused; but in Step 4, the "Main Thread" is continuously executed.

Please help me explain that make me confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows messaging is an event based system. Your program sits in a loop, checking the message queue and responding to events.

This means that when your program looks like it's waiting for you to click the OK button on the message box, it's still listening for and responding to events. One of those events would be the `BN_CLICKED` for the OK button, but another is a timer message.

If the program ever really pauses, your program will become unresponsive.

Comment: @MarkRanson: two functions OnTimer() and OnBtnStartClicked() are executed in two threads or only one?

Comment: @quangdien only one thread. When Windows was first created, there were no threads! It used cooperative multitasking, where the only way for a program to run was for another program to pause while waiting for a message.

Comment: In addition, all the messages received in a Window Procedure are on the same thread in which the window was created--even if the message is sent from another thread.  So, WM_TIMER and BN_CLICED or any message you process will be on the same thread.

Comment: I have one more question, in the case i want to synchronize two messages (ex:message box of timer is displayed if and only if user clicks on OK btn of first message box). Do you have any suggestion?